# How to format number without decimal part but preserving floating point?

Tags: c#

I need to format a double, rounding it to 0 decimal places, but preserving the floating point. Whatever I found removes the floating point in case there is no decimal part:

```
string result = String.Format("{0:0.}", 12.3);
```

Comment: So in this example you would want your result to be 12.0?

Comment: No, I would want it to be 12.   , thus keeping the period in place.

Comment: If you want the result as a string you could just add + "." at the end.

Comment: Well, `String.Format("{0:0}.",12.3)` would do the trick, no?

Comment: `string result = String.Format("{0:0}.", 12.3);` ?

Comment: Or if you want it to work across cultures: `string result = String.Format("{0:0}", 12.3) + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;`

Comment: Please explain: "12.3" = "12." and "12" = "12" or = "12." ?

Comment: Igor, both should be 12.0

Comment: Thank you Spender and Matthew, this will do the trick. As spender happened to be the first, could you please add you solution as an answer, so that I could mark it accordingly? Sam, thank you, too.\

Comment: Use Math.Round(12.3) if you aren't sure how to round

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:** (Really formatting a double)

```
string result = String.Format("{0:0\\.}", 12.3);
```

**or simply:** (Adding dot after)

```
string result = String.Format("{0:0}.", 12.3);
```

**Sample:**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/B0hlud

Happy to help you!

Comment: This keeps 0, which should not happen.

Comment: You answered "Igor, both should be 12.0".. I Updated the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, it was my mistake. I meant 12.